# How to run python file in java project?

Tags: java, python, selenium-chromedriver

I've got a python file which opens a webpage with selenium.How can I run this file in java application ? I tried Runtime().exec("python main.py") and "python3 main.py" but it did't work.

Comment: Why are you not using Selenium in Java?

Comment: Make sure the `pyhton` command is in the path. Also, provide the full absolute path to the script you want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ProcessBuilder.

```
String[] commands = { "python", "main.py" }; // Need to add a python or python3 to the system path
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.directory("Set the path of the main.py folder");
Process proc = pb.start();
```